# Parse.com public API Error Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, http, parse-platform

When trying to perform an anonymous request from a JS environment to a public parse.com application I'm getting http error 401 Unauthorized

In the parse.io app settings "Allow anonymous users" is ON

This is the request as I can see it in DevTools, any insights will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's much insight to be given, CORS is supported, everything is working fine, but Parse is saying the user is not authorized. You have to either check your settings again, or contant Parse ?

Comment: What are the security settings for CLPs on that class ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Security settings are 'public read + write'.

Answer (score 1):

It's `X-Parse-JavaScript-Key` in the header, not `REST-API` nor `Javascript-Key`. Works fine now.